# ngClass mat-radio-button if checked / Angular

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I am iterating these mat-radio-button:

```
planes = [
  { nombre: '3 días', costo: 0 },
  { nombre: '7 días', costo: 0 },
  { nombre: '15 días', costo: 0 }
];
```

I want to add a class only for which it is selected: `[ngClass]="{'border border-secondary': checked}"`

but I don't get any results:

```
<mat-radio-group class="d-flex flex-column" formControlName="plan">
  <mat-radio-button class="my-1 border rounded p-3" *ngFor="let plan of planes; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'border border-secondary': checked}" [value]="plan.nombre">
    <div class="d-flex justify-content-between">
      <span class="h4 w-100">{{plan.nombre}}</span>
      <span class="text-muted">{{plan.costo | currency : 'S/ '}}</span>
    </div>
  </mat-radio-button>
</mat-radio-group>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can refer to the button wih a [template reference variable](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#template-reference-variables-var) `#btn` and get the value of its `checked` property. Depending if you are adding one or several classes to the checked button, you can use one of the following [class binding](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#class-binding) syntaxes:

```
<mat-radio-button #btn [class.border-secondary]="btn.checked" ... >
<mat-radio-button #btn [ngClass]="{ 'border border-secondary': btn.checked }" ... >
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w1yksm-rytaro?file=app/radio-ng-model-example.html) for a demo.

---

If a component class property is bound to the radio group (e.g. `[(ngModel)]="selectedNombre"`), you can determine if a radio button is checked by comparing the bound value to the radio button value:

```
<mat-radio-button [class.border-secondary]="selectedPlane === plane.nombre" ... >
<mat-radio-button [ngClass]="{ 'border border-secondary': selectedPlane === plane.nombre }" ... >
```

---

An alternative is to take advantage of the fact that Angular Material already adds the class `mat-radio-checked` to the selected radio button. You can then add additional styling in CSS:

```
mat-radio-button.border.mat-radio-checked {
  border-color: red;
}
```

See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-w1yksm-sggfrn?file=app%2Fradio-ng-model-example.css) for a demo.

Comment: I prefer the way `{ 'border-secondary background-checked': favoriteSeason==season }"`

Comment: @Eliseo - I added your suggestion to the answer. That is what I tried first in my stackblitz but I found it less obvious for reactive forms (used by the OP, as shown in the question).

Comment: This: `[class.border-secondary] =" btn.checked"` and this: `mat-radio-button.border.mat-radio-checked {
  border-color: red;
}` worked for me, thank you very much.